# Keycloak support for one realm on a domain name while serving on multiple domains simultaneously

Tags: security, openid, keycloak

I'm building an ecosystem of applications on kubernetes with keycloak as authentication/authorization provider. I am(or probably was) planning for everything to be integrated with it via OpenId(OAuth2) and for user credentials and other private information never to leave the keycloak instance in an unencrypted form.

I was trying to implement the whole authentication scheme with the following configurations in mind.

### Realms

```
myservice: Realm containing the public and back-office users of my application. 
           All microservices that I have are authenticating users against this realm.

master:    Contains admins, keycloak administrators and other resources which 
           should not be ever exposed to the public or intranet users. No microservice 
           ever performs authentication on this realm.
```

### Domains

```
 1. domain: account.myservice.com
    access: public
    cors: allow requests from app.myservice.com
    config: kubernetes-ingress
    exposes: configured themes to support login, registration, etc.. Endpoints 
        for public front-end application token validation
    description: Only exposes access to a realm called "myservice" in keycloak. 
        No users from other realms can login or interact.

2.  domain: account.internal.myservice.com
    access: intranet/admins
    cors: allow requests from back-office.internal.myservice.com
    config: kubernetes-ingress
    exposes: configured themes to support login, registration, etc.. Endpoints 
        for back-end front-end application token validation
    description: Exposes all the realms and provides access to keycloak 
        administrative UI.

3.  domain: keycloak (keycloak.default.svc.cluster.local)
    access: cluster-internal
    cors: none
    config: kubernetes service, visible only inside the cluster
    exposes: endpoints for back-end application token validation
    description: Only exposes realm "myservice" and is used for other services to 
        validate user tokens and similar stuff.
```

I did come across a number of issues when trying to implement the above configuration scheme. If I do SSL termination inside Keycloak I won't be able to configure the different domains via a reverse proxy or similar approach which, in turn, means that Keycloak should provide a feature to listen on a separate SSL encrypted port and only make one realm available there. Which it does not. So do I want something weird here? Are the best practices different from what I want?

Comment: I would really like to know if you settled on a solution to this problem, without terminating SSL on the proxy. I have a similar set up.
Terminating SSL on the proxy, you can easily rewrite the host, thus, using the second domain exclusively on the proxy. Like here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65033538/how-to-combine-nginx-stream-and-http-for-the-same-servername

Comment: @MikeByte I did proxy my traffic on the main internet-looking gateway without decryption. There's a protocol supported by haproxy(possibly by others also) which attaches the source IP addresses to proxied & encrypted traffic. Then I had another, secured, proxy server sitting right in front of keycloack which set the X-Forwarded-For, and if traffic was coming from the internet gateway only allowed it to work with the public keycloak realm(you can't limit internet users not logging into other realms otherwise). And traffic from the intranet had other rules. Hope this helps :)