# How to combine nginx "stream" and "http" for the same servername?

Tags: nginx

I would like to handle 2 servernames, say "web1.example.com" and "web2.example.com" on the same port (443) in the same nginx config where the first should be a local `http` server, and the second needs to be forwarded to an external upstream without terminating the SSL connection.

How do I configure this?

Details:

I can use nginx to look at the first SSL message (CLientHello) and use it to proxy/forward the entire connection without terminating SSL. This can even look at the SNI and choose a different upstream based on the servername in it. This uses the [ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html) with `proxy_pass` and `ssl_preread on`. The config is something like this:

```
stream {
    upstream web1 {
        server 10.0.0.1:443;
    }
    upstream web2 {
        server 10.0.0.2:443;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
        web1.example.com web1;
        web1-alias.example.com web1;
        web2.example.com web2;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;

        resolver 1.1.1.1;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;

        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

This is configured in the `stream` config section of nginx.

But I can also configure a local http server in the `http` config section of nginx.
So what if I want web1 ("web1.example.com" in the example) to use such a "local nginx http server", and not an external "upstream server"? ("web2" should still be forwarded as before.) So I want to configure "web1.example.com" in the `http` config section of nginx, and "forward" to it in the `stream` config section of nginx.

To be clear, I want "web1.example.com" to be configured like this:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name web1.example.com web1-alias.example.com;

        ssl_certificate ...
        location ...
        ...
    }
}
```

This all works find if I do either `stream` or `http` listening on the same port. But how do I do both on the same port?
How can I "call" the `http` config section from the `streams` config section? Can `proxy_pass` refer to a local nginx `http` server somehow?

Comment: Current conclusion: It's not possible, but you can work around it.
But I'd gladly be proven wrong by a new answer ;-)
My personal workaround is to use another port on which I run `rinetd`. (Not the most elegant solution perhaps, but using `rinetd` it was very easy to forward without terminating the SSL connection.)

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can use both on the same port, but maybe something like this would work?

```
stream {
    upstream web1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:8443;
    }
    upstream web2 {
        server 10.0.0.2:443;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
        web1.example.com web1;
        web1-alias.example.com web1;
        web2.example.com web2;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;

        resolver 1.1.1.1;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;

        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8443 ssl;
        server_name web1.example.com web1-alias.example.com;

        ssl_certificate ...
        location ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, an interesting workaround. Is this still efficient? A new TCP connection needs to be set up. How does this impact performance?

Comment: @CoderNr23 I didn't use such configurations in production, but in theory you are not limited to TCP connection for this type of configuration and can use a UNIX socket as well, it should be less performance impact.

Comment: I have a UDP proxy setup, and I've been trying to figure out a proper value to give to `proxy_timeout`. The example given in the Nginx Docs (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/) show 3 seconds, which is what I have, but I still get "upstream timed out" every now and then.

Comment: What is "resolver 1.1.1.1;" for? Wouldn't nginx use the host's DNS facility?